# Usar pca en imagen hiperespectrales con el toolbox Laurens van der Maaten en matlab

Tags: matlab

Alguien podria ayudarme a entender como puedo usar el pca de 
Laurens van der Maaten en matlab. 
El toolbox esta en 
http://lvdmaaten.github.io/drtoolbox/#usage
tengo instalado el toolbox en matlab 
tengo la imagen hiperespectral indian Pines leida

pero como hacer uso de PCA para yo poder identificar las bandas que no me sirven como las que tienen mucho ruido y no sirven de nada? en la ayuda dice

coeff = pca(X)

Despues de leer la imagen hiperespectral las dimensiones son
145x145x200

Donde esta contiene 200 bandas pero como puedo usar PCA para yo poder identificar los principales componentes y el otro resto de bandas como las ruidosas usando el grafico para visualizar cada banda

Necesito usar figure(graficar con imshow o imagesc) para visualizar cada banda y ver cuales son muy ruidosas para despues quitarlas